# Flutter - Map not working when addAll function call

Tags: flutter, dart, mobx

This the code I have right now (I'm using Mobx):

```
@observable
ObservableMap dates = ObservableMap();

@action
void getDate() {
  final Map obj = {};
  final map = item['dates'].map((date) {
    DateTime key = DateTime.parse(date['date']);

    obj.addAll({
      key: ['list']
    });
  });

//    print(map);
  dates.addAll(obj);
}
```

I have function to call query  and call `getDate` function.

At my UI I just call the `dates` but it won't return any value. The value only return if the `print` syntax not comment.

Any solutionn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `map` method to do something for each element of `item['dates']`. That doesn't work because the `map` operation is *lazy* and doesn't do anything until you start *using* the result. You can call `.toList()` on the result to make it do all the computations, but that's a roundabout way to do it.

Use `forEach` instead to eagerly do something for each element, or, even better, use a `for-in` loop:

```
item['dates'].forEach((date) { ... });
```

or

```
for (var date in item['dates']) {
  var key = DateTime.parse(date['date']);
  obj.addAll({key: ['list']});
  // or just:
  // obj[key] = ['list'];
}
```

Comment: thank you. just learn something new. Map is lazy. I thought for statement will reduce performance.